# Is this a convex set?

Tags: convex-geometry

Is set A convex when set A = the union of all points on a circle and all points in the interior of the circle, minus point R?

Comment: It depends on where $R$ is.

Comment: You are asking if a punctured disc, similar to an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) is convex?  So long as the point where the puncture occurs is in the interior, then no.  Suppose the puncture occurred at point $(x_0,y_0)$.  Then for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ you have $(x_0-\epsilon,y_0)$ and $(x_0+\epsilon,y_0)$ do not have the entire line segment connecting them in your set.  If it is on the exterior, then sure it is.

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to add. Point R is on the circle.